# Custom weblogic log format

Tags: logging, log4j, cargo, weblogic14c

I have application running through cargo-maven3-plugin (1.9.4) on weblogic14x container.
I would like to modify weblogic log to exclude fields which are not important for me.

Currently log looks like this:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] <19 gru 2022, 13:12:33,731> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <log message from my application>
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
<log message from my application>
```

Is there a way to do that in weblogic14? I was able to do something similar in older weblogic versions but I didn't find anything for this one.

Even an extremaly ugly hack would be fine, I don't care as long as it will work ;)

Comment: Are you sure this log snipet is from WebLogic Server's log ? It should start with "####"

Comment: In https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/standalone/weblogic-server/14.1.1.0/wllog/logging_services.html#GUID-17D72415-0B1D-4372-BA3A-C0829E98AE9E they said:

`When a WebLogic Server instance writes a message to standard out, the output does not include the ####        prefix and does not include the Server Name, Machine Name, Thread ID, User ID, Transaction ID, Diagnostic Context ID, and Raw Time Value fields.`

So, `[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]` comes from cargo plugin and rest is from weblogic

Comment: So, it is not the WebLogic Server log itself but the standard output. 
If you want to change log messages pattern you have to update your application's log configuration (log4j for instance)

Comment: but lo4j from my application will affect only <log message from my application>. I will still get  <19 gru 2022, 13:12:33,731> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> which is part of weblogic output